# What is the security benefit of verifying iOS Apps Receipts on the Apple App Store, vs in-app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to understand the benefit of verifying a reciept within the app itself, vs asking the app to send it to a server for validation.

I've read [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) and for some reason the payload is sent here:

```
AppleProductionUrl = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
AppleTestUrl = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
```

As it stands now, I still need to validate various aspects of the certificate: BundleID, etc.  X509 properties should be an easy thing I can do to increase privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Real answer: none, because you don't care about eastern-European hackers who are twice as smart as both of us combined. If they hack my app, they can have it, it costs me nothing.

Paranoid answer: you can't trust the client! Someone might have decrypted and decompiled it!111!

In reality - if you have renewing subscriptions (auto-subscriptions), or, you have testflight users who might be testing purchases in the sandbox (aka sandbox users), then, in order to do **any** receipt validation you need to care about which environment you're in. An example of the former: your auto-renewing subscription expires tomorrow. Did Apple succesfully auto-charge their credit card? Better find out before locking them out of your app...